# PayPal Donate button that accepts subscriptions

Tags: paypal

I'm hoping there's an accepted method for this, as I seem to be able to get it to *kind* of work.

I have a donate form that has an optional 'One-off/Every month' select box.

Ideally the user should be able to either donate a one-off amount, or create a donation subscription.

The issue I'm facing is that there's a subscription button, and there is a donate button, but no *donate* subscription button.

So the code I've cobbled together so far almost works:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="24" />
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="X" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="X" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="X" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Donate now" />
</form>
```

(`X` replacing sensitive values)

So this will pass the user to a page that at least looks kind of right:

[image: preview]

It's a donation form, with a subscription checkbox - almost there!

However you'll notice that the amount isn't present, and the recurring box isn't ticked.

If I include the `amount` attribute with the form then none of the subscription bits show up, and it reverts to a standard donation page.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible? I mean it really should be, but the only content on the PayPal site that refers to it (via a Google search) takes me to a 404 page, so who knows: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/create-recurring-donation-button

(It's also not on the WayBack machine, unfortunately)

The description text on Google looks promising… so I'll keep my fingers crossed that somebody knows what used to be on that page…

Edit: The above link appears to be functioning correctly now. Must be due to some weird territory/permissions bug, as yesterday while logged in it was just a 'Sorry this page does not exist' page; logging out seems to have granted me access to PayPal's knowledge.

However the content is a tad ambiguous (maybe):

> The instructions below will show you how to create a recurring donation button by creating a Subscription button, then changing some of the HTML … to make it appear as a Donate button.

I'm not sure I really see any advantage to this - are they saying this process will create a subscription button that just *looks* like a donation button? Not sure what the purpose of that would be…

Comment: The PayPal page you referenced is not throwing a 404 (at least not for me, right now), and some of the other top google hits also seem to work & have the same advice. In short, they say to create a subscriptions button and edit it to be donations-like; the donations button doesn't really handle recurring donations properly.

Comment: That's… really weird. When I view that URL I'm just getting 'Sorry that page doesn't exist'.

Comment: But it's a shame if that's the advice, as I've found that elsewhere. Surely that then just becomes a subscription button? Which I assume doesn't carry any of the advantages of 'paying' in the form of a donation? So how is it any different than a bog-standard subscription button? Maybe you've seen something I haven't, please feel free to share any good looking advice. The method I attempted that sounds similar just created a subscription button. Nothing 'donation-like' about it, unless you just mean the button graphic?

Comment: Interestingly that page is now loading for me. Only difference? I'm not logged in to PayPal. Must be some weird territory/permissions thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with PayPal this morning on the phone I can confirm that @geewiz and the common advice is definitely the way to go. i.e. just use a standard subscription.

The piece of the puzzle I was missing (partially due to this being work for a client) is that the fee's applied are based on the *account*, not the *payment type*. i.e. a 'donation' through paypal is no different than any other payment, it's just a different button (and a slightly modified form at the other end).

If you're registered as a charity etc. then a standard subscription is sufficient, and the walkthrough provided by PayPal in my OP is the best resource for that. Just be warned that you might see a 'Sorry, that page doesn't exist' message when visiting the link. Logging out of PayPal worked for me.

Comment: Right. The donations flow is just cosmetic variation of the regular website payments standard flow; there are no functional differences (such as different funding source eligibility or different fee structures).

Comment: That is correct - something I hadn't realised until now!